# Adding a Search feature to my Kotlin android application

Tags: android, kotlin, search, android-activity

I'm having some issues finding out how to implement a search feature that will filter my list based on what is typed in to the search. I have tried a few different methods and just cannot seem to get this to work. I have a search field in my layouts with the id searchView. If anyone has any advice on how I might implement this in to my activity I would be so grateful. I'm hoping this is not too vague in terms of the code.

Many thanks.

My activity is as follows:

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import org.wit.hikingtrails.R
import org.wit.hikingtrails.adapters.HikeAdapter
import org.wit.hikingtrails.adapters.HikeListener
import org.wit.hikingtrails.databinding.ActivityHikeListBinding
import org.wit.hikingtrails.main.MainApp
import org.wit.hikingtrails.models.HikeModel
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast


class HikeListActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HikeListener/*, MultiplePermissionsListener*/ {

    lateinit var app: MainApp
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHikeListBinding
    private lateinit var refreshIntentLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHikeListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.toolbar.title = title
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView)


        app = application as MainApp

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        loadHikes()
        registerRefreshCallback()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item_add -> {
                val launcherIntent = Intent(this, HikeActivity::class.java)
                refreshIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
            }
            R.id.item_add -> {
                val launcherIntent = Intent(this, HikeActivity::class.java)
                refreshIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
            }
            R.id.logout -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                val launcherIntent = Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)
                refreshIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

        override fun onHikeClick(hike: HikeModel) {
        val launcherIntent = Intent(this, HikeActivity::class.java)
        launcherIntent.putExtra("hike_edit", hike)
        refreshIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
    }

    private fun registerRefreshCallback() {
        refreshIntentLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
            { loadHikes() }
    }

    private fun loadHikes() {
        showHikes(app.hikes.findAll())
    }

    fun showHikes (hikes: List<HikeModel>) {
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = HikeAdapter(hikes, this)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not spam with irrelevant tags (`java` removed)

Comment: You need to go through this: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/search There's a fair bit of stuff involved in making that `SearchView` actually do something!